# Rename variables of one dataframe by joining the values of another dataframe by using a Loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, concatenation

I have two dataframe.
The first dataframe has the directions

df1

```
   Direction 
0  sb
1  nb
2  wb
3  eb
```

The second df2 is

```
   LT Thr RT UT LT.1 Thr.1 RT.1 UT.1 LT.2 Thr.2 RT.2 UT.2
0  
1
2
3
```

I want to be able to loop through the names of df2 and rename them by concatenating using the direction df as follows:

df2

```
   sb_LT sb_Thr sb_RT sb_UT nb_LT nb_Thr nb_RT nb_UT wb_LT wb_Thr wb_RT wb_UT
0  
1
2
3
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your `sb` at 1st index and `nb` at 0th index. so is it a mistake?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated it to be consistent.

Comment: @joshuah9 What is the relation between the `directions` in `df1` and column names in `df2`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma the relationship between the 2 tables would be that df2 has the movement of traffic, LT, Thr, RT, UT, etc for each leg of an intersection that is why they repeat. df1 has the direction of the approach.

Comment: @joshuah9 Is there any sequential relation between the index of `df1` and the `numbers` that are suffixed to the column names in `df2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
new_columns = [df1.iloc[1,0]+"_"+x.split(".")[0] if '1' in x else 
               df1.iloc[2,0]+"_"+x.split(".")[0] if '2' in x else 
               df1.iloc[3,0]+"_"+x.split(".")[0] if '3' in x else 
               df1.iloc[0,0]+"_"+x.split(".")[0] for x in df2]

df2.columns = new_columns
```